# Meaning of "group" part in declare implementaion dependencies of Gradle

Tags: gradle

In build.gradle, we define dependencies in implementation section, such as

```
dependencies {
  //for dependencies found in artifact repositories you can use
  //the group:name:version notation
  implementation 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'

  //map-style notation:
  implementation group: 'com.google.code.guice', name: 'guice', version: '1.0'
}
```

(I get an example here https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html)

I want to know the meaning of **group** part in this declaration, because when I leave it empty or set it anything, Gradle still works. Example:

```
dependencies {
  implementation ':commons-lang:2.6'
  // or
  implementation 'abc-xyz:commons-lang:2.6'
}
```

I want to know the purpose Gradle using it.

Thanks for your answer.